# Possible to render and raise exception in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, render

I have been fighting with this for some hours now. I have a controller action that I want to render a page and then raise an exception automatically. I couldn't find much information on this that makes me think that I am looking for the wrong thing.

Is something like the below possible?

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base

  def new
    # .. do stuff
    begin
      UserMailer::send_confirmation_link(@user)
    rescue StandardError => e
      render 'email_error'
      raise(e)
    end
    # .. other stuff
  end

end
```

In this case I simply want to inform the end-user of the error and then raise the exception on the application itself. Notice that I can't change the de-facto error page since this is a smaller application in the same codebase with a bigger application.

Answer (score 3):

No, you either render or raise an exception, not both.

Rails does provide both the static `500.html` page in `public` which is what's rendered by default for exceptions, you can customize the message your users see for all exceptions there.

Also there's the `rescue_from` method that you can use to customize the response for a specific exception class, and that's a good way to have a central spot (usually in `ApplicationController`) where the exception responses are all located.

If you were doing this with your use case you would probably want your own custom exception class, a subclass of `RuntimeError`, that you would wrap this exception in to re-raise, like:

```
rescue StandardError => e
  raise EmailConfirmationError.new e.message
end
```

...and then in your `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from EmailConfirmationError { |e| render "email_error" }
```