# No template found for RegistrationsController#update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to raise an error then render the edit page for the registrations controller. But when I hit the error the page freezes and I get this error.

```
No template found for RegistrationsController#update rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 698ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

Here is my controller action

```
def update
    resource.transaction do
      super do |user|
        if membership_params.present?
          ToggleAlertEmails.perform(user: current_user, params: membership_params)
        end

        if user.errors[:current_password].present?
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
          redirect_to edit_user_registrations_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

When I hit that `raise ActiveRecord:Rollback` it actually rollback the changes like I want but it doesn't continue on and render the edit page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may want to refer to this answer from stack overflow, but make sure to read the question, the situation is similar to yours.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460895/possible-to-render-and-raise-exception-in-rails-controller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `redirect_to edit_user_registrations_path` outside the transaction, using a flag (`error` in the example below) to redirect only when the rollback is executed, something like this:

```
def update
  error = false

  resource.transaction do
    super do |user|
      if membership_params.present?
        ToggleAlertEmails.perform(user: current_user, params: membership_params)
      end

      if user.errors[:current_password].present?
        error = true
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  end

  redirect_to edit_user_registrations_path if error
end
```

Or, if your prefer, avoid the flag and use `user.errors[:current_password].present?` again:

```
redirect_to edit_user_registrations_path if user.errors[:current_password].present?
```

Although the specific error you posted is because there is no view for `update` action (e.g. `update.html.erb`), so you will need to create one or specify another render/redirect through `render`/`redirect_to`.

If you want to redirect to `edit` always, then avoid the final `if` and keep the `redirect_to` only:

```
redirect_to edit_user_registrations_path
```

If you want to redirect to another action or render a different view (that is, neither `update` nor `edit`) when there is no rollback, use a complete `if`/`else` statement:

```
if user.errors[:current_password].present?
  redirect_to edit_user_registrations_path
else
  redirect_to other_action_path
end
```

Just remember, no matter which scenario you chose, the render/redirect should be added outside your transaction.